# Can an abbr tag's title be styled?

Tags: css, abbr

Take the following code:

```
<abbr title="World Health Organization">WHO</abbr>
```

Can we style an abbr tag's title? So that instead of a custom tooltip we can use title?

Comment: FYI on Firefox the abbr tag has a dotted underline to indicate there's something worth hovering over, but not on Chrome or IE. But they can be styled to have it like so: http://html5doctor.com/the-abbr-element/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you mean style the actual text that pops up, no you can't style that with CSS; it's browser-specific. Javascript-based `tooltips` would be the way I would handle it, since it allows to have more control over this behavior.

Comment: https://inclusive-components.design/tooltips-toggletips/ seems to be on a better track…

Answer (score 28):

Actually, Alex Mcp’s answer is incorrect. It is entirely possible to do this with CSS for modern browsers. However, a fallback for older browsers with JavaScript may be used.

```css
abbr {
    position: relative;
}

abbr:hover::after {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 100%;
    display: block;
    padding: 1em;
    background: yellow;
    content: attr(title);
}
```

This will add an absolutely positioned pseudo element top right of the abbr tag using the attribute content within the title when the abbr tag is hovered over.

Comment: I see the yellow background but `content: attr(title);` isn't working. There's no text.

Comment: It actually does work if you give the element that contains the abbr `position: relative;`

Comment: am I the only one this doesn't work for?  even @SoonDead's fiddle doesn't work.  if you leave the cursor on the abbr long enough you will see the old tooltip show up as well

Comment: @George yes that is true. you can [use javascript](http://jsfiddle.net/sSMKx/33/) to replace the tag and mimic functionality.

Comment: Tried this today with Yandex and found the answer from @alex-mcp to be correct despite the difference in votes given this approach does not actually style the browser's pop-up tooltip, it emulates it. In my case I **saw two tooltips at the same time** using this approach: one faux and the other from the browser.

Answer (score 4):

I was looking for something similar and came up with the following alternative (tested on Firefox, Safari and Chrome on Mac, works with IE 7-10 when I clicked it), based on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1682714/can-an-abbr-tags-tittle-be-styled):

**HTML:**

```
<abbr title="My Custom Abbreviation" name="">Abbreviation</abbr>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('[title]').each( function() {
    var mytitle = $(this);
    mytitle.data('title',mytitle.attr('title')); // get title attribute value
mytitle.attr('name', mytitle.attr('title')); // add title attribute value to NAME attribute
    mytitle.removeAttr('title'); // remove the title attribute, removing browser tooltip
});
```

**CSS:**

```
abbr {
    position: relative;
}
abbr:hover::after {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 100%;
    display: block;
    padding: 1em;
    background: yellow;
    content: attr(name);
}
```

Comment: add `width:max-content;` to the pseudo element. This will give one line tooltip. Also we can use `data-title` instead of name attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You can style the way the shortened version appears, so in this case 'WHO'. But not the way the pop up box appears, as that is controlled by the browser/OS.

You can get around this limitation by applying some [JQuery](http://www.jquery.com) stuff to any `abbr` tag programatically - this would display a `div`, of which the contents would read the same as the `title` on the tag that called it.

Comment: No, <acronym> is deprecated. Use <abbr>.