# Can you style a <abbr> tag?

Tags: html, abbr

Can you style a `<abbr>` tag using css? In firefox, it is displayed with dots underneath the words like in the picture below:
[image]

Is this a browser by browser thing? can you remove the dots or do you just use the `title="title here"` option?
thanks

Comment: Does [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/abbr#Default_styling) [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/abbr#Browser_compatibility) help?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- Can you style a  tag using css?

  Yes, you can.
- In firefox, it is displayed with dots underneath the words

  Yes. Firefox default style is

  ```
  abbr[title], acronym[title] {
      border-bottom: 1px dotted;
  }
  ```
- Is this a browser by browser thing?

  Yes, this behaviour is determined by the default stylesheet of each browser. Then, different browsers may display it different by default.
- Can you remove the dots?

  Yes, just override the default syle:

  ```
  abbr[title], acronym[title] {
      border-bottom: none;
  }
  ```

Answer (score 22):

Firefox 40 has a small change:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Releases/40/Site_Compatibility#CSS

To remove default underline in Firefox, you now need to set CSS:

```
text-decoration: none;
```

Comment: Can confirm on Chrome 58 atm

Answer (score 7):

It is possible to style the  tag with CSS for modern browsers. However, a fallback for older browsers with JavaScript may be used. (But who wants to support IE 8?)

```
abbr {
position: relative;
}

abbr:hover::after {
position: absolute;
bottom: 100%;
left: 100%;
display: block;
padding: 1em;
background: yellow;
content: attr(title);
}
```

This will add an absolutely positioned pseudo element top right of the  tag using the attribute content within the title when the  tag is hovered over.

Comment: Thank you! That will be useful too.

Comment: If you do this, you could end up seeing both the ::after content as well as the browser-generated tooltip, which looks pretty bad IMHO. You're probably better off going a JS route if styling tooltips is something important to you.

Answer (score 2):

Mr. Bunnyman.

Seems like your experiencing a cross browser issue.

Yes, you can style `<abbr>` tag. Example below.

```
abbr { border: 2px dashed red; }
```

If your experiencing an underline on a certain browser, try:

```
abbr { border-bottom: 0px !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Can you style a `<abbr>` tag using css?

Yes, but you *cannot* style the `title` attribute—though you can [fake it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11383105/712334) unreliably.

> Is this a browser by browser thing?

Yes, default styles are set in the user agent stylesheet.

> Can you remove the dots?

Absolutely. To remove them unset the [`text-decoration` property](https://devdocs.io/css/text-decoration) in your stylesheet:

```
abbr[title] {
  text-decoration: unset;
}
```

Inclusive design approaches are [also possible](https://inclusive-components.design/tooltips-toggletips/).

Answer (score -1):

You can style any HTML element with any CSS you want, the problem is, for some HTML elements it will have no effect.

In other words, you can add the CSS to whatever the heck you want, but the browser may not support your changes. 
i.e. Styling the `<head>` element is possible, but it is pointless.

Comment: Downvoted: This answer is confusing and self contridictory. It also doesn't answer the OP's question.

Comment: So, you can style any element but you can't style any element, right?

Comment: It's an old answer - but as tested now, July 2021, in Firefox and Chrome the <head> element responds to css styling.  Tested with: <style>head {visibility:visible; display:block; background:#f00; height:100px; width:100px;}</style>