# Is it possible to override existing html tags?

Tags: javascript, html, markdown, client-side

So, I tend to write my documents in markdown and I recently discovered that I could create abbreviations in markdown. This is great, but I had already created my own version of the abbreviation tag as I didn't like the way the standard tag looked when rendered. Is there a best practice to overriding existing tags?

The below text is to explain what I am trying to achieve in equivalence to. I cannot modify the markdown parser itself as I host my site on Github pages. For those who want to know how I have my own HTML tag, I use [Polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org/) to create these tags.

## Markdown Text:

```
 Markdown converts text to HTML.

*[HTML]: HyperText Markup Language
```

## Converted Code:

```
<p>Markdown converts text to <abbr title="HyperText Markup Language">HTML</abbr>.</p>
```

## I want it converted to:

```
<p>Markdown converts text to <short-text abbr="HTML">HyperText Markup Language</short-text>.</p>
```

Comment: You could use JavaScript.  In particular you could use the jQuery library and call the document.Ready function to manipulate the DOM.

Comment: Have you considered using CSS to make it look the way you want?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I have in the past when I created the tag, however, I [lose a lot of control over how my tag functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1682714/can-an-abbr-tags-title-be-styled).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's all simple text, and you're doing this to all `abbr` tabs, you can simply build a new element and replace the old one.

With jQuery (for simplicity):

```
jQuery("abbr").each(function() {
    var title = jQuery(this).attr("title");
    var text = jQuery(this).text();
    var $new = jQuery("<short-text></short-text>").attr("abbr", text).html(title);
    jQuery(this).replaceWith($new);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After the page is loaded and the Markdown is parsed, try something like this (supported in ES5, nothing external required for supporting browsers):

```
document.querySelectorAll('abbr').forEach(function(el) {
  var newEl = document.createElement('shortText');
  newEl.setAttribute('abbr', el.innerHTML);
  newEl.innerHTML = el.getAttribute('title');
  el.parentNode.replaceChild(newEl, el);
});
```